# Problem in determining the polindrome string

Tags: c++

A task was given in which it was necessary to determine whether the entered word (or phrase) is a palindrome (this is a verbal construction that can be read both from left to right and from right to left). As a result, finding the word palindrome did not cause any special problems for me, here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool polindrom(string pol)
{
    int len = pol.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len / 2; i++)
    {
        if (pol[i] != pol[len - i - 1])
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

int main()
{
    string pol;
    cout << "Enter the phrase: " << endl;
    cin >> pol;
    if (polindrom(pol))
    {
        cout << "This phrase is a polindrome.";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "This phrase is not a polindrome.";
    }
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

However, if you enter an expression-palindrome (for example, Able was I ere I saw Elba), then the program will no longer be able to determine what it is. Moreover, by the condition of the task, it is also necessary to delete everything that is entered after the point (including the point itself). Help implement this. I understand that when you enter an expression, the program starts reading spaces, but of course they do not converge from the left and right sides, only how can we make it ignore and not read spaces and capital letters?

Comment: put return true; outside loop

Comment: I suggest you do some debugging of your `polindrom` function. At least [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) but also take it as a good time to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code statement by statement.

Comment: Sorry, I can not resist: _polindrom_ -> **palindrome**. ;-)

Comment: For debbuging I would 1. check the string in pol. 2. how are upper and lower case handled.

Comment: May also want to look up what `std::string (pol.rbegin(), pol.rend())` does, e.g. [std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Allocator>::rend](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rend)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `cin >>` which extracts the input separated by space.

Here is your code, slightly modified to take input character by character, ignore spaces and convert all alphabets to lower case (ignore capitalization) and discard everything after the period. You can see the code live [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/s0u3l8Z8h5bwsg3R)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool palindrome(string pol)
{
    int len = pol.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len / 2; i++)
    {
        if (pol[i] != pol[len - i - 1])
        {
            return false;
        }
   }

   return true;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string input;

    cout << "Enter the phrase: " << endl;

    char c;

    while(cin.get(c)) {
        // discard input after period
        if (ispunct(c))
            break;
        // ignore space
        if (isspace(c))
            continue;
        // convert upper to lower case
        input += tolower(c);
    }

    cout << "Input phrase: " << input << endl;

    if (palindrome(input))
    {
        cout << "This phrase is a palindrome.";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "This phrase is not a palindrome.";
    }

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but how to make sure that all punctuation marks are excluded except for the dot. I undestand that if a write like that: if (ispunct(c)) {continue;} - all punctuation marks (including the period) will be ignored.

Comment: You can use ```if (c == '.')``` instead of ```if (ispunct(c))``` to ignore only period.

Answer (score 0):

> how can we make it ignore and not read spaces and capital letters?

You can read an entire line from the input stream with [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

```
#include <string>
// ...
std::string line;
while ( std::getline(std::cin, line) )
{
    // Do something with line...
}
```

Then, "pre-process" the string, removing all the spaces and punctation characters and also convert to lower case all the capitol letters.

```
#include <cctype>
// ...
std::string simplify(std::string const& str)
{//                              ^^^^^^ I don't want unnecessary copies
    std::string result;

    for (unsigned char ch : str)
    {
        if ( std::isspace(ch) or std::ispunct(ch) )
        {
            continue;
        }
        result.push_back(std::tolower(ch));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now it is ready to be checked.

```
bool is_palindrome(std::string const& str)
{
    for (size_t i = 0, j = str.length(); i < j; ++i)
    {
        if ( str[i] != str[--j] )
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```